# Best way to convert an InputStream object to String

Tags: java, string, inputstream

I have an `InputStream` object which contains several million file informations (Name, create date, author etc.) in `XML` format. I've already tried to convert it to `String` using `IOUtils.copy` method, but since the size of that information is pretty large it throws an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, after running for few minutes.

Increasing `JVM` memory is not an option, since the number of files, which I collect info from, is increasing forever. So can someone suggest me what should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: What's the concrete implementation of the `InputStream`? Is it a `ByteArrayInputStream`, for example?

Comment: If the input is just too massive, your other options are (a) First trying to ETL it into a database or (b) using Hadoop or something similar

Comment: It just seems to be the wrong approach to convert the huge data into one string. What do you want to do with the string?

Comment: If you can't fit your object in memory, then avoid cases that requires you to store it in memory. Work with it as stream.

Comment: @manouti I don't have a clear understand which type of `InputStream` it is since I receive if from a 3rd party API using `HttpResponse response.getEntity().getContent()`

Comment: Use an XML REST or SOAP library, for Java there are about a billion. InputStream is too low level.

Comment: @ControlAltDel my tool is intended to create as a standalone application to list files and their info if needed so using something like Hadoop is not an option

Comment: @user1666090 to read those file info I need to convert it to a JSON object

Comment: If the data is too large to store in memory and you can't increase memory then your options are limited - either process as a stream, extracting what you need, or persisting the data somewhere for later access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are having is the **very reason** stream based IO exists, it is simply not viable to slurp huge amounts of data into memory before consuming it.

Parse your stream as... a stream! See the [`Oracle tutorials`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) for more information on stream based XML parsing using SAX.

```
XMLReader xmlreader =
    SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
xmlreader.setContentHandler(new ContentHandler() {
    ...
});

xmlreader.parse(new InputSource(myInputStream));
```